# What was the design language used by Google prior to modern Material design?

Tags: google, google-materials-design, design-language

You can still find it in *very few* places. Like Google Groups (see example). But even that, understandably, is getting a redesign, one that hides quite a bit of functionality and seems to dispose entirely of some (e.g. some filter options).

Screenshot:
[image: Classic Google Groups design following design language used across the company products ca. 2012]

I recall it was a "thing" with some PR work popularizing its launch across different Google products as a unification of their interface designs. I can't recall its name and no query gets me anything similar. And sadly there's no such thing as a compiled "history" of design languages used by a company even one as big as Google.

Answer (score 2):

Before Material, each Google product had a handful of designers working on their respective product without a common design ethos.

You can read the entire story (which is really fascinating) in this article:
https://www.fastcompany.com/3046512/how-google-finally-got-design

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [Project Kennedy](https://www.theverge.com/2013/1/24/3904134/google-redesign-how-larry-page-engineered-beautiful-revolution)? There was a brief period where Google was gung-ho on implementing it everywhere before going quiet and releasing Material in 2014.